# Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route` Google Map React

Tags: reactjs, react-props, google-maps-react

I'm getting this warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route` when trying to construct a google map.

Here is the App:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";

class Maps extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cd-map">
        <h3>Map Component</h3>
        <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14}>
          <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick} name={"Current location"} />
          <InfoWindow onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}>
            <div>
              <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "API-Key"
})(Maps);
```

Routes:

```
var React = require('react'); 
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom'); 
var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, hashHistory} = require('react-router'); 
var Main = require('Main'); 
var Intro = require('Intro'); 
var Instructions = require('Instructions'); 
var Maps = require('Maps'); 

ReactDOM.render( 
<Router history={hashHistory}> 
  <Route path="/" component={Main}> 
    <IndexRoute component={Intro}/> 
    <Route path="instructions" component={Instructions}/> 
    <Route path="maps" component={Maps}/> 
  </Route> 
</Router>, 
document.getElementById('app') 
)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing you're using react router, can you show where you define your routes? Or wherever `Route` is defined

Comment: @Geraint See above.

Comment: Also, I have an alias in webpack.config file. Maps: 'app/components/Maps.jsx'

Answer (score 2):

It works by changing "export default WrappedMap" to "module.exports = WrappedMap;". cause JS uses

```
 module.exports
```

as convention, however this means that you are just working with a regular Javascript object. Google Api doesn't return a component.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with react google maps but it looks like whatever GoogleApiWrapper returns isn't a proper component like react-router expects. Try doing something like this:

```
const WrappedMap = GoogleApiWrapper({
   apiKey: __APIKEY___
})(Container);

export default WrappedMap
```

Comment: That worked! I just changed "export default WrappedMap" to "module.exports = WrappedMap;". Thanks for your help.